# Why Carbon Black detected Code Injection from Outlook and Excel

Tags: excel, outlook

We have observed Outlook and Excel attempted code injection by calling the function "SetWindowsHookExW," resulting in blocks by Carbon Black endpoint protection.

We would like to understand if this behavior is expected and why these applications are attempting code injection.

Alerts:

- Outlook: The application "c:\program files\microsoft office\root\office16\outlook.exe" attempted to inject code into the process "c:\program files\microsoft office\root\office16\outlook.exe" by calling the function "SetWindowsHookExW." The operation was blocked by Carbon Black.
- Excel: The script "\desktop\file\B_list.xlsx" attempted to inject code into the process "c:\program files\microsoft office\root\office16\excel.exe" by calling the function "SetWindowsHookExW." The operation was blocked by Carbon Black.

Thank you.

I am not very technical, and I am unfamiliar with these issues. Has anyone encountered them before? Or could anyone explain on possible reason for this?

Comment: Similar issues found with wordpad.exe in 2021. Issue fixed in sensor version 3.7.0.1411
https://community.carbonblack.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Carbon-Black-Cloud-wordpad-exe-attempted-to-inject-code-into/ta-p/108156